# Wrong IO actions order using putStr and getLine

Tags: haskell, io, ghc, buffering

I have the following code:

```
main = do
    putStr "Test input : "
    content <- getLine
    putStrLn content
```

When I run it (with `runhaskell`) or compile it (ghc 6.10.4) the result is like this:

```
asd
Test input : asd
```

Why is `Test input : asd` being printed after `asd`?

In the code sample on http://learnyouahaskell.com/, which uses `putStr`, the `getLine`'s presented output is different than mine. When I use `putStrLn` the program works as expected (print, then prompt, and print).

Is it a bug in `ghc`, or it is the way that it should work?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

This is because ghci disables buffering, while a program compiled with ghc has line buffering by default. You can see this by running this:

```
import System.IO
main = print =<< hGetBuffering stdout
```

In ghci you see `NoBuffering` while with runghc you get `LineBuffering`. Since the newline character doesn't print until *after* the user input, the prompt doesn't either.

Fix it by adding `hFlush stdout` after your prompt (or disable buffering with `hSetBuffering stdout NoBuffering`, but that’s probably bad).

Comment: you might need `import System.IO` instead of `import IO`

Comment: @KamilSzot: I am experiencing the same symptoms while using System.IO

Comment: Is there a reason to leave it buffered?