# Why isn't my IO executed in order?

Tags: haskell, io, buffering

I got a problem with IO not executing in order, even inside a do construct.

In the following code I am just keeping track of what cards are left, where the card is a tuple of chars (one for suit and one for value) then the user is continously asked for which cards have been played. I want the `putStr` to be executed between each input, and not at the very end like it is now.

```
module Main where
main = doLoop cards
doLoop xs = do  putStr $ show xs
                s <- getChar
                n <- getChar
                doLoop $ remove (s,n) xs
suits = "SCDH"
vals = "A23456789JQK"
cards = [(s,n) | s <- suits, n <- vals]
type Card = (Char,Char)
remove :: Card -> [Card] -> [Card]
remove card xs = filter (/= card) xs
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

absz's answer is correct, Haskell's buffered IO is what's causing you trouble. Here's one way to rewrite your `doLoop` to have the effect you're looking for:

```
doLoop xs = do  putStrLn $ show xs
                input <- getLine
                let s:n:_ = input
                doLoop $ remove (s,n) xs
```

The two changes: use `putStrLn` to append a newline and flush the output (which is probably what you want), and use `getLine` to grab the input a line at a time (again, probably what you want).

Comment: Bad code ! You introduce a potentiel pattern match failure here.

Comment: True, the case is far from exhaustive, but as a proof of concept (regarding the IO operations) it does the job.

Answer (score 14):

If the problem is what I think it is, your problem is that Haskell's IO is buffered: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2500459/wrong-io-actions-order-using-putstr-and-getline) explains what's happening.  When you run a compiled Haskell program, GHC stores output in the buffer and only periodically flushes it to the screen; it does so if (a) the buffer is too full, (b) if a newline is printed, or (c) if you call `hFlush stdout`.

The other problem you may be seeing is that `getChar` may not fire until a newline is read, but then the newline is in your input stream; you could perhaps solve this with an extra `getChar` to swallow the newline, but there should probably be a better way.

Comment: Yep, good call. Just tried it myself; works fine in GHCi, prints nothing until the end when compiled, just like the question you linked to.

Answer (score 6):

Buffering, in the form of putStr, is your problem, as others have pointed out.

Also, a style point: `putStrLn $ show xs` is the same as `print xs`