# Prompt message disappears in compiled executable?

Tags: haskell

I have a Haskell program that shows a prompt and then accepts input from the command line. I'm doing this as:

```
main = do putStr "Please enter program source file name: "
          programFileName <- getLine
          programFileHandle <- openFile programFileName ReadMode
          program <- hGetContents programFileHandle
          putStr "Please enter initial file configuration file name: "
          initConfigFileName <- getLine
          initConfigFileHandle <- openFile initConfigFileName ReadMode
          initConfigStr <- hGetContents initConfigFileHandle
          print (evaluateProgram (lines program) (readReg initConfigStr))
```

When I run it on the GHCi interpreter, the prompts show up fine and I am able to enter my inputs (and everything else works).

e.g. 
    *Main> main
    Please enter program source file name: sum.urm
    Please enter initial file configuration file name: sum.conf
    9

When I compile it though (on Mac OS X or Windows), it produces an executable that does not show my prompts. It waits for the two input strings, and then once I have put in the valid filenames, it prints the prompts and the result.

e.g.

```
$ ./a.out 
sum.urm
sum.conf
Please enter program source file name: Please enter initial file configuration file name: 9
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

For the curious, I was implementing an [Unlimited Register Machine](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition%3aUnlimited_Register_Machine) in Haskell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard output stream, `stdout`, is line buffered by default. That means that it will only be written to the console every time you output a `\n` character, or finally when the program terminates. You can fix this by importing `System.IO` and doing `hFlush stdout` after every `putStr` that doesn't contain a `\n` at the end.

Comment: Note also that GHCi sets stdin and stdout to be unbuffered, which is why you get the behaviour you expect there.

Comment: Another potentially simpler solution is to do `hSetBuffering stdout NoBuffering`. Then `putStr` will do the expected thing.

Comment: Thanks. I had to do `hFlush stdout` instead of `hFlush stdio`, but it gave me the idea.

Comment: Oh, sorry, that was a typo. It's of course supposed to be `stdout`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a buffering issue. Here are related questions, with several choices for solutions:

[Why isn't my IO executed in order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706635/why-isnt-my-io-executed-in-order)

[Execution order with (>>=) not what I expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8361508/execution-order-with-not-what-i-expected)