# printing menu in terminal and choosing an option, how to?

Tags: haskell, command-line, io, buffering

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Wrong IO actions order using putStr and getLine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2500459/wrong-io-actions-order-using-putstr-and-getline)

I'm a haskell beginner.

I'm trying to make a program that shows a menu through terminal and ask user to introduce an option. Here is the code:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    putStrLn "0    <- quit"
    putStrLn "1    <- Hello"
    putStr "Choose an option: "
    c <- getChar
    case c of
        '0' -> return ()
        '1' -> putChar '\n' >> putStrLn "Hello World" >> main
```

When I use this module in the ghci interpreter everything works like it's suposed to do.
But if i compile this with:

> ghc hello.hs

and run it in the terminal, it doesn't display the line "Choose an option:" before ask for a char to be introduced.
I think this may be caused because of haskell lazy nature and I don't know how to fix it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

It's not due to laziness, just buffering. Use `putStrLn` instead of `putStr` and it will work.

See [Wrong IO actions order using putStr and getLine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2500459/wrong-io-actions-order-using-putstr-and-getline)

Comment: thanks! just solve it by flushing the buffer